# Why does as.factor return a character when used inside apply?

Tags: r, apply, r-factor

I want to convert variables into factors using `apply()`:

```
a <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100),
                x2 = sample(c("a","b"), 100, replace = T),
                x3 = factor(c(rep("a",50) , rep("b",50))))

a2 <- apply(a, 2,as.factor)
apply(a2, 2,class)
```

results in:

```
         x1          x2          x3 
"character" "character" "character"
```

I don't understand why this results in character vectors instead of factor vectors.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`apply` converts your data.frame to a character matrix. Use `lapply`:

```
lapply(a, class)
# $x1
# [1] "numeric"
# $x2
# [1] "factor"
# $x3
# [1] "factor"
```

In second command apply converts result to character matrix, using `lapply`:

```
a2 <- lapply(a, as.factor)
lapply(a2, class)
# $x1
# [1] "factor"
# $x2
# [1] "factor"
# $x3
# [1] "factor"
```

But for simple lookout you could use `str`:

```
str(a)
# 'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x1: num  -1.79 -1.091 1.307 1.142 -0.972 ...
#  $ x2: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
#  $ x3: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Additional explanation according to comments:

### Why does the lapply work while apply doesn't?

The first thing that `apply` does is to convert an argument to a matrix. So `apply(a)` is equivalent to `apply(as.matrix(a))`. As you can see `str(as.matrix(a))` gives you:

```
chr [1:100, 1:3] " 0.075124364" "-1.608618269" "-1.487629526" ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "x1" "x2" "x3"
```

There are no more factors, so `class` return `"character"` for all columns.
`lapply` works on columns so gives you what you want (it does something like `class(a$column_name)` for each column).

You can see in help to `apply` why `apply` and `as.factor` doesn't work :

> In all cases the result is coerced by
>   as.vector to one of the basic vector
>   types before the dimensions are set,
>   so that (for example) factor results
>   will be coerced to a character array.

Why `sapply` and `as.factor` doesn't work you can see in help to `sapply`:

> Value (...) An atomic vector or matrix
>   or list of the same length as X (...)
>   If simplification occurs, the output
>   type is determined from the highest
>   type of the return values in the
>   hierarchy NULL < raw < logical <
>   integer < real < complex < character <
>   list < expression, after coercion of
>   pairlists to lists.

You never get matrix of factors or data.frame.

### How to convert output to `data.frame`?

Simple, use `as.data.frame` as you wrote in comment:

```
a2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(a, as.factor))
str(a2)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x1: Factor w/ 100 levels "-2.49629293159922",..: 60 6 7 63 45 93 56 98 40 61 ...
 $ x2: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ x3: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

But if you want to replace selected character columns with `factor` there is a trick:

```
a3 <- data.frame(x1=letters, x2=LETTERS, x3=LETTERS, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(a3)
'data.frame':   26 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x1: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ x2: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
 $ x3: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...

columns_to_change <- c("x1","x2")
a3[, columns_to_change] <- lapply(a3[, columns_to_change], as.factor)
str(a3)
'data.frame':   26 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x1: Factor w/ 26 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ x2: Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ x3: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
```

You could use it to replace all columns using:

```
a3 <- data.frame(x1=letters, x2=LETTERS, x3=LETTERS, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
a3[, ] <- lapply(a3, as.factor)
str(a3)
'data.frame':   26 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x1: Factor w/ 26 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ x2: Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ x3: Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Comment: Great Marek,
Thanks.

I see that the remaining thing to do is use as.data.frame on the output.

I do wonder though, why does the lapply works while apply doesn't ?

Thanks,
Tal

Comment: Yup... if you want `data.frame` use `as.data.frame(lapply(dtf, fun))`. `sapply` will do the same thing as `apply`. Don't know why, but maybe it has something to do with the fact that `data.frame` is actually a list... `lapply` returns `list`, so it's easily convertible to `data.frame` if you do that on `sapply` or `apply` output, you're trying to coerce `numeric` to `data.frame`, hence mess things up... it is strange, but not an "unforeseen" behaviour, I must admit!

Comment: Or do `a[] <- lapply(a, as.factor)`