# Using Apply on a data.frame with character and numeric variables

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert some exsiting loop based code to use R's apply function.  As per the specs fo this project, **no additional libraries** (e.g. plyr) are allowed.

This is how it currently works.

> ```
>   Type Pressure Temp
> 1   Iron      100   10
> 2 Copper      200   20
> ```

```
for(i in 1:rnow(data))
{
    if(data$Type[i] == "Iron")
         Output[i] <- IronCalculation(data$Pressure[i]...)
    else if(data$Type[i] == "Copper")
         Output[i] <- CopperCalculation(data$Pressure[i]...)
}
```

I want to convert this to use the `apply()` function.  I've tried a number of ways, but I'm simply stuck because `apply()` converts all variable values into characters, and so numeric compilations on these are not possible.  The original data set has 150+ variables, many of which are strings/characters.

As a test I've tried the following.  Obviously it fails.  I can convert the the character variables to numbers using as.numeric(), but there are 8000+ rows and 20 variables in each.  Seems like waste of CPU cycles.

```
apply(data[1,], 2, function(x) {
if(x['Type'] == "Iron")
             Output <- IronCalculation(x['Type'],x['Pressure']...)
})
```

Can anybody help?  How can I change this loop to use an apply function?

Comment: Could you precise what you have tried ?

Comment: Is it 1 row per type? What inputs exactly do the calculations take?

Comment: this doesn't happen to be homework does it? `data$iron` doesn't exist in your sample data... did you mean `data$Type`? I'd suggest looking at `switch` and writing your own custom function that wraps up your nested `if else` stuff.

Comment: Right now there are 5 types and the calculation for each type takes about 20 variables from each row.  So IronCalculation() inputs 20 variables and does a lot of calculations with these variables.

Comment: I wish this was homework...then I would only be failing in school :)  I meant data$Type, not data$Iron - sorry for the error.

Comment: you want to write a function that uses `switch(data['Type'], Iron=IronCalculation(...), Copper=CopperCalculation(...))`.  Then `apply(data, 1, yourswitchfunction)`

Comment: I think if you provide a small before data set and a small after (expected) data set we'd get a better idea of what you're trying to achieve as I'm pretty sure there's better approaches than what you're using.

Comment: I agree with @TylerRinker . A small example start and desired end would help a lot. `apply()` may not even be the right function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is as.factor returns a character when used inside apply?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392216/why-is-as-factor-returns-a-character-when-used-inside-apply)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
apply(data, 1,  
  function(x) {  
    if (x['Type'] == 'Iron')  
      IronCalculation(as.numeric(x['Pressure']), as.numeric(x['Pressure']))  
    else if (x['Type'] == 'Copper')  
      CopperCalculation(as.numeric(x['Pressure']), as.numeric(x['Pressure']))  
  }  
)
```

and you will get a vector.  `as.numeric()` is necessary because both `Pressure` and `Temp` are coerced to character when passed along with `Type` to your anonymous function.

Edit: But using `switch()` as suggested by @Justin instead of nested `if`s would be much more ellegant.