# R User-defined function works alone but returns incorrect values when used with apply

Tags: r, function, apply, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance

The user defined function (dist.func) runs and provides the correct output when I use it on a single line of data but does not provide the correct output (still executes) when I embed it into the apply() command. In this case, I want to calculate by rows.

Apologies for the complex sample data included, but values have to fall within a threshold to return meaningful outputs, and this is the easiest way to ensure that happens.

```
library(fields)
```

The function is essentially measuring between XY coordinates (Euclidian distances with rdist() command), but it first takes a subset of the data keeping only those rows of the 'TO' data that fall within a given similarity (Euclidian distance between the first and second principal components, PC1 and PC2).

This makes the sample data:

```
# This data is the reference points to measure FROM
FROM <- data.frame(X=c(-4187500,-4183500,-4155500,-4179500,-2883500),
               Y=c(10092500,10084500,10020500,10012500,9232500),
               PC1=c(-0.525,-0.506,-1.146,-0.733,-1.160),
               PC2=c(3.606,3.609,4.114,3.681,0.882))

# This data is the destination points to measure TO
TO <- data.frame(X=c(-4207500,-4183500,-4203500,-4187500,-2827500,-4203500,-4199500,-4183500,-4195500,-4191500),
             Y=c(10100500,10100500,10096500,10092500,10092500,10088500,10084500,10084500,10072500,10064500),
             PC1=c(-0.371,0.447,-0.344,-0.026,-0.652,-0.460,-0.313,0.010,-0.293,-0.319 ),
             PC2=c(3.149,4.619,3.318,3.885,0.407,3.164,3.300,3.892,3.226,3.337))

# This is the threshold of the data similarity match (distance between PC1 and PC2 in both data sets)
threshold <- 0.5
```

Here is my user-defined function (with each line explained):

```
dist.func <- function(REF){
  # Calculate the similarity (PC1 and PC2 distance) to all points in the destination
  # Select only those under the threshold
  bt <- as.matrix(TO[(rdist(REF[3:4],TO[3:4])[1,]<threshold)==T,c("X","Y")])
  # Calculate the number of points under the threshold (the "sample size")
  # If there are no points uder the threshold, the SS is set to zero (otherwise 'NA' kills the loop)
  ss <- ifelse(nrow(bt)>=50, 50 ,nrow(bt))
  # If/else to deal with SS=0
  if (nrow(bt)>0) {
    # Calculate the euclidian distance between the reference point and all points under the threshold
    # This calculates the distances, sorts them in ascending order, and trims to the sample size
    dst <- rdist(REF[1:2],bt)[1,][order(rdist(REF[1:2],bt)[1,])][1:ss]
  } else {
  dst <- c(NA)
  }
# Report (in a list or table or whatever) the summary stats for the distances 
list(
  p05=ifelse(nrow(bt)==0, NA, quantile(dst,0.05)),
  MIN=ifelse(nrow(bt)==0, NA, min(dst)),
  AVG=ifelse(nrow(bt)==0, NA, mean(dst)),
  N=ifelse(nrow(bt)==0, 0, nrow(bt)))
}
```

And here's the test with a single line of the FROM data (working) and embedded into the apply() command (not returning correct values):

```
# Using the function on a single line of data returns correct values for the given line
dist.func(FROM[1,])

# Embedding the function into apply() returns incorrect outputs
# I'm committed to using apply() here (or some variant) to avoid a for() loop by rows
apply(FROM, 1, dist.func)
```

I'm fairly new with user-defined functions, so any suggestions there would be appreciated, if that's where the problem lies. Also, if there's a way to make the function or the code in general more efficient (a package I'm not familiar with), that would be most welcome also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lapply` gives the correct output

```
  my.list<-as.list(1:nrow(FROM))

k- lapply(my.list,function(i)dist.func(FROM[i,])
kk<-do.call(rbind,k) # convert to data.frame

sapply(my.list,function(i)dist.func(FROM[i,]))
    [,1]     [,2]     [,3] [,4] [,5]
p05 14939.76 16242.64 NA   NA   NA  
MIN 14422.21 16000    NA   NA   NA  
AVG 19795.44 21179.25 NA   NA   NA  
N   6        6        0    0    0
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why this must be done through lapply() or sapply() as opposed to apply() by rows? Would be helpful to understand this for the future.

Comment: Also, my real data has tens of thousands of rows, so using sapply() to output a table isn't pracitcal. Is there a slick way to get a matrix or data frame output WITHOUT transposing the sapply output or converting the list to a data frame (as both processes will result in a table too large for R)?

Comment: No problem. Good question!, but I don't have an answer right now. May be this can be posted as a new question; I am also curious to know that. Please see the updated answer for converting to data.frame; you can assign result to k to avoid getting large tables in console and then using `head(k)` or `head(kk)`

Comment: Actually, that do.call() command returns exactly what I'm after. Thanks again!

Comment: David & Metrics, see the answer by Ferdinand.kraft.  Also check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392216/why-does-as-factor-return-a-character-when-used-inside-apply) for a more detailed approach.  I've run into the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `apply` converts `FROM` to a matrix. Compare:

```
> dist.func(FROM[1,])
$p05
[1] 14939.76
$MIN
[1] 14422.21
$AVG
[1] 19795.44
$N
[1] 6

> dist.func(as.matrix(FROM)[1,])
$p05
[1] 1400
$MIN
[1] 1e-10
$AVG
[1] 179500
$N
[1] 8

> apply(FROM, 1, dist.func)[[1]]
$p05
[1] 1400
$MIN
[1] 1e-10
$AVG
[1] 179500
$N
[1] 8
```