# Why does `apply(df, 2, class)` shows every column to be characters?

Tags: r

```
> d <- data.frame(s=c("a", "b", "c"), n=c(1,2,3)) 
> apply(d, 2, class)
```

Even the `d` has a string and a numeric column, the second line shows that everything is character? Why?

And since this method is inaccurate, what is a way to check the type of multiple columns in a data frame?

Comment: Use `sapply(d, class)`.

Comment: The first sentence of the Details section in `?apply` states that it coerces it to a matrix.

Comment: See @Marek's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392216/why-does-as-factor-return-a-character-when-used-inside-apply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apply` coerces your data frame into a matrix. Try `lapply` instead:

```
lapply(df, class) 
$s
[1] "factor"

$n
[1] "numeric"
```