# How can you get table(·) in R to output column names in factor order instead of alphabetic order?

Tags: r

I have a variable to be interpreted as 1:3 = c("M","F","NB").  (This is a column in a large data frame.)  When I convert this with

```
df$gend <- factor(df$Q99,labels=c("M","F","NB"),levels=1:3)
```

it processes fine.  But when I use `apply(·)` to the entire data.frame with `FUN=table`, it reports the results ordered alphabetically instead of by factor-label ordering.

But, when I try to replicate this in a stand-alone toy data set:

```
table(factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3),labels=c("M","F","NB"),levels=1:3))
```

the result is as would be expected, in the order of M, F, NB.

I have tried to read thru the help for `?table`, and I cannot figure out how it is deciding to order (or not order) the output for the frequency table.

If there is an argument for either `table(·)` or `apply(·)`, I would love to know what it might be.

Comment: Related about the "`apply` issue": [Why does as.factor return a character when used inside apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392216/why-does-as-factor-return-a-character-when-used-inside-apply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the OP used `apply` with `MARGIN =2`, it will transform the data.frame to `matrix` and the `factor` would change it to `character`.  Instead, if we want to apply the `table` on the whole dataset, use `lapply`

```
lapply(df, table)
```

---

Reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(letters[1:6], 10 *5, replace = TRUE), 10, 5))
df[] <- lapply(df, factor, levels = letters[1:6])
```

Now, we test with `apply` and `lapply`

```
apply(df, 2, table)
lapply(df, table)
```

The reason is that `apply` is converting to `matrix` behind the hood (source code of `apply`)

```
...

if (is.object(X)) 
        X <- if (dl == 2L) 
            as.matrix(X)
        else as.array(X)
        
 ...
```

According to `?apply`,

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array.

and this result in removing the attributes to change the column `class` to `character`

```
apply(df, 2, class)
#         V1          V2          V3          V4          V5 
#"character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

whereas

```
lapply(df, class)
#$V1
#[1] "factor"

#$V2
#[1] "factor"

#$V3
#[1] "factor"

#$V4
#[1] "factor"

#$V5
#[1] "factor"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  As a separate query, how might I have known that `table(·)` was converting the data.frame to a matrix...I really didn't see any reference to that in the help page.

Comment: @GreggH it is not `table` converting to `matrix`. It is the `apply` method which works mainly for `matrix`, but can also be done on data.frame

Comment: @GreggH It is specified in the `?apply` `If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array.`